# Gradle 8: Unable to make progress running work. There are items queued for execution but none of them can be started

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, gradle, teamcity

In my Selenium-JAVA-Gradle based automated test project running in CI: Teamcity server, recently we updated the JAVA and Gradle version. The tests run good without any error locally but the build in TeamCity marked as failure. What could be the reason?

- Teamcity server - JAVA Version: 21
- Teamcity server - Gradle Version: 8.4

All the tests runs good without any error, but the build marked as failure with the error:

```
 Unable to make progress running work. The following items are queued for execution but none of them can be started:
10:49:51     - Build ':':
10:49:51         - Waiting for nodes:
10:49:51             - :build (state=SHOULD_RUN, dependencies=NOT_COMPLETE, group=task group 2, dependencies=[:assemble (SHOULD_RUN), :check (EXECUTED)], waiting-for=[:assemble (SHOULD_RUN)], has-failed-dependency=false )
10:49:51             - :clean (state=SHOULD_RUN, dependencies=COMPLETE_AND_SUCCESSFUL, group=task group 1, dependencies=[Resolve mutations for :clean (EXECUTED), producer locations for task group 0 (EXECUTED)], has-failed-dependency=false )
10:49:51         - Nodes ready to start:
10:49:51             - :jar
10:49:51             - :clean
10:49:51         - Reachable nodes:
10:49:51             - :jar (state=SHOULD_RUN, dependencies=COMPLETE_AND_SUCCESSFUL, group=task group 2, dependencies=[Resolve mutations for :jar (EXECUTED), destroyer locations for task group 1 (EXECUTED), :classes (EXECUTED), :compileJava (EXECUTED)], has-failed-dependency=false )
10:49:51             - :assemble (state=SHOULD_RUN, dependencies=NOT_COMPLETE, group=task group 2, dependencies=[:jar (SHOULD_RUN)], waiting-for=[:jar (SHOULD_RUN)], has-failed-dependency=false )
10:49:51         - Scheduling events:
10:49:51             - node added to plan: destroyer locations for task group 0, when: scheduled, state: SHOULD_RUN, dependencies: 0, is ready node? true
10:49:51             - node added to plan: destroyer locations for task group 1, when: scheduled, state: SHOULD_RUN, dependencies: 2, is ready node? false
10:49:51             - node added to plan: producer locations for task group 0, when: scheduled, state: SHOULD_RUN, dependencies: 5, is ready node? false
10:49:51         - Ordinal groups:
10:49:51             - group 0 entry nodes: [:test (EXECUTED)]
10:49:51             - group 1 entry nodes: [:clean (SHOULD_RUN)]
10:49:51             - group 2 entry nodes: [:build (SHOULD_RUN)]
10:49:51     - Workers waiting for work: 4
10:49:51     - Stopped workers: 0
10:49:51   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to make progress running work. There are items queued for execution but none of them can be started
```

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: In teamcity: 'Build Step: Gradle' -> set 'Gradle tasks: clean build test' -> 'Additional Gradle command line parameters: %TEST_ENV% --warning-mode all'  This configuration fixed my issue.